# XCode: Could not launch "APP_X_Y" - 'A' packet returned an error: -1

Tags: ios, xcode4, certificate, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to get my App to work again on the simulator as well as on my device. Before I got this error, I went through an odyssee of XCode signing errors, but right know it seems like I'm really stuck.

**The error:**

When I try to launch the App on a device, it builds without any errors, but after installing the app I get the error message:

**Could not launch "APP_X_Y" - 'A' packet returned an error: -1**

Unfortunately I cannot use the **Simulator** either - it **gets stuck** at "Attaching to APP_X_Y". You can also take a look at the simulator problem over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382968/xcode-4-hangs-at-attaching-to-app-name) - but there is no final solution out there.

**What I've done so far:**

After different XCode Errors I went through the following Stackoverflow questions, each helping me out with to get to the next level.

1. [Xcode: failed to get the task for process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601304/xcode-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process)
2. [Profile bug (Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process XXX.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720597/profile-bug-error-launching-remote-program-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process)
3. [Code Sign error: Provisioning profile can't be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758154/code-sign-error-provisioning-profile-cant-be-found)
4. [Provisioning Profile "Team" is "Unknown"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180329/provisioning-profile-team-is-unknown)

In the last step, however I think things got really screwed up: XCode wasn't able to find the provisioning profile anymore, that's why I've deleted my provisioning profile string in my project file, like it is recommended over here: [Codesign error: Provisioning profile cannot be found after deleting expired profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760518/codesign-error-provisioning-profile-cannot-be-found-after-deleting-expired-prof)

Know I'm struggling with the packet returned -1 error and I cannot find any input out here. Has anyone an idea how to get this to work again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a new project from scratch, can this new project connect to the simulator? In that case I suggest just moving over the existing code and settings to a fresh project. I've had to resort to this at least once that I can remember because something fishy had gone wrong with the XCode project file.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but it works... Another way to solve this issue would be a roll back to an older working project file.

Comment: Yea well, I agree it's not a pretty solution, but it's at least pretty simple and you get the bonus of knowing your project isn't filled up with gunk from previous versions...

Answer (score 18):

Got the same error when attempting to deploy an application to the third of three connected devices.

All I had to do was quit XCode and restart it and then it worked fine again.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same error. Cleaned build folder, emptied derived data folder, deleted app from device, restarted xcode and it worked again.

Comment: Worked for me too. Much easier than recreating the project.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers helped me.. I wasn't able to launch ANY apps in Xcode 5 until I uncluttered my `/etc/hosts` file - leaving just the basics...

```
::1                     localhost
127.0.0.1               localhost
255.255.255.255         broadcasthost
fe80::1%lo0             localhost
10.0.1.100              XYZ.com
2001:470:XXXX::100      XYZ.com
```

You must edit the file as root, btw... `sudo nano /etc/hosts`