# Xcode lldb error in lauch program

Tags: xcode, macos, lldb

i get smilar error when i try launch my application (c++ command line) from xcode , (the application work fine from terminal .

[XCode: Could not launch "APP_X_Y" - 'A' packet returned an error: -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731412/xcode-could-not-launch-app-x-y-a-packet-returned-an-error-1)

i tried every mentioned solution in above question but none of them helped me.

i finally found problem is launching using LLDB so GDB works fine. but i want to debug my program using LLDB and launch with default config in xcode.

the error is in following lldb function:

```
Error
PlatformRemoteGDBServer::LaunchProcess (ProcessLaunchInfo &launch_info)
{
    Error error;
    lldb::pid_t pid = LLDB_INVALID_PROCESS_ID;

    m_gdb_client.SetSTDIN ("/dev/null");
    m_gdb_client.SetSTDOUT ("/dev/null");
    m_gdb_client.SetSTDERR ("/dev/null");
    m_gdb_client.SetDisableASLR (launch_info.GetFlags().Test (eLaunchFlagDisableASLR));

    const char *working_dir = launch_info.GetWorkingDirectory();
    if (working_dir && working_dir[0])
    {
        m_gdb_client.SetWorkingDir (working_dir);
    }

    // Send the environment and the program + arguments after we connect
    const char **argv = launch_info.GetArguments().GetConstArgumentVector();
    const char **envp = launch_info.GetEnvironmentEntries().GetConstArgumentVector();

    if (envp)
    {
        const char *env_entry;
        for (int i=0; (env_entry = envp[i]); ++i)
        {
            if (m_gdb_client.SendEnvironmentPacket(env_entry) != 0)
                break;
        }
    }
    const uint32_t old_packet_timeout = m_gdb_client.SetPacketTimeout (5);
    int arg_packet_err = m_gdb_client.SendArgumentsPacket (argv);
    m_gdb_client.SetPacketTimeout (old_packet_timeout);
    if (arg_packet_err == 0)
    {
        std::string error_str;
        if (m_gdb_client.GetLaunchSuccess (error_str))
        {
            pid = m_gdb_client.GetCurrentProcessID ();
            if (pid != LLDB_INVALID_PROCESS_ID)
                launch_info.SetProcessID (pid);
        }
        else
        {
            error.SetErrorString (error_str.c_str());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        **error.SetErrorStringWithFormat("**'A' packet returned an error: %i",** arg_packet_err);**
    }
    return error;
}
```

as you can see 'a' packet error is in lldb now question is how can fix this problem ? is there any solution to reinstall / reconfigure LLDB in xcode? can anyone find where is problem from lldb function.

i'm using latest Mac OS + Xcode 4.6.3 latest

please share your ideas .

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Xcode? That should be 4.6.3. If not, please update.

Comment: yea i'm using latest any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

This error happens when `debugserver` cannot launch the app you are trying to debug.  `debugserver` launches, attaches, stops, inspects and controls the process - it is a small program with all of these responsibilities.  It communicates to lldb (possibly inside Xcode) via the "gdb remote protocol", with some minor extensions.

If you've built your own lldb, chances are that `debugserver` is not properly code signed so it cannot launch apps.

If you've changed your `/etc/hosts` file, check that you have a line like `127.0.0.1    localhost` in there.  Some people have modified their `/etc/hosts` (I have no idea why) and removed this line, and this has caused problems for lldb trying to communicate with debugserver.

Otherwise, check the output in `Console.app` to see if there are any useful messages logged.

Comment: thanks for at least one answer

i didn't build lldb by my self (default thing) /etc/hosts is in good shape 127.0.0.1 localhost and here is Console.app log :

user.local com.apple.debugserver-200[5547]: debugserver-200 for x86_64.
user.local com.apple.debugserver-200[5547]: Listening to port 40485...
so where is problem ?

Comment: Try opening TextEdit from `/Applications`.  Then in Terminal see if `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Resources/debugserver localhost:1234 --attach=Textedit` works.  If debugserver can't attach to TextEdit, debugging isn't going to work at all.

Comment: here is output : ./debugserver localhost:1234 --attach=Textedit
debugserver-200 for x86_64.
Listening to port 1234...

Comment: Doesn't look like a permissions problem. You can try getting one step closer to the code path Xcode is using by creating a do-nothing a.out binary in /tmp, then do `.../debugserver localhost:1234 /tmp/a.out` then in another Terminal do `xcrun lldb /tmp/a.out`; `(lldb) gdb-remote 1234`, `b main`, `c`.  But you're probably going to need to collect the log file showing the packets between lldb & Xcode and file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com/.  put `log enable -f /tmp/packets.txt gdb-remote packets` in your `~/.lldbinit`, launch Xcode, repo, & attach that log file to the bug report.

Comment: I'd recommend trying to understand the scope of the problem.  Is it your system?  Your project?  Create a new Mac app (new > Project > one of the sample Cocoa apps), can you launch it in Xcode?  Stop at a breakpoint?  Can you attach to a process like TextEdit from within Xcode?  What about Simulator apps -- launch & attach?  What about iOS device apps - launch & attach?  My guess is that you don't have *complete* debugger failure, there is some specific combination that is not working and finding what works & what doesn't work will help narrow down what is going wrong.

Comment: it's not only my problem i tried other mac and had same problem xcode version is 4.6.3 latest i tried new project and didn't work the problem is actually launching from XCode project will get build and work from terminal but not in xcode with lldb (gdb works) it will fail on cocoa app / command line tool . tried IOS app and simulator launched .

Comment: There is something specific to your project or setup.  I would recommend collecting the packet log (mentioned previously) and filing a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com/ . I haven't heard of any other people having problems like this with Xcode 4.6.3.

Comment: i already reported this issue to apple (from bugreport) and still got no answer from them ...

Comment: THANK YOU! my problem was indeed on my hosts file which did not have an entry for localhost. lifesaver.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation. It happened after updating to Xcode 5 in my case.
After all it works fine now.

I followed the command line executions as per the comment from [Jason Molenda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1692151/jason-molenda).

When running "xcrun lldb ..." I got an error:

```
xcrun error failed to exec real xcrun. (no such file or directory)
```

After Googling, I figured this out:

```
xcode-select -print-path
/Developer
```

As my Xcode was not in there, I did:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

I don't know why, but it didn't work immediately in my case. After quitting Xcode, Terminal, etc., Xcode ran and debug worked as expected.

Comment: Wrong path ""/Applications/Xcode.app" changed to "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"